# Error exception runtime

Tags: android, exception, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, runtime-error

I add this code to my broadcast, my broadcast runs when my program in background and then runs this code that is in my broadcast. but when run this code, the program crashs ! why? How can i solve this problem?

```
Intent intentUp=new Intent();
        intentUp.setComponent(new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),ActivityForUp.class.getName()));
        intentUp.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
```

and ActivityForUp activity in manifest :

```
<activity 
        android:name="org.example.sendandreceivesms.ActivityForUp">
        <intent-filter >

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

logcat:

```
calling startactivity() from outside of an activity context requires the flag_activity_new_task flag
```

I write ture manifest file? Shoud i add action tag? if yes, what write this and why?
Thanks for advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write intentUp instead of intent in statrActivity() method.